# MessageBox acting weird

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a very weird problem.

I tried to run this code and whenever I pressed the space key it print multiples 'A' as I want.

comments: the code is inside main, `Key.IsPressed` is using WinAPI `GetKeyState` method and the space constant is the virtual key of the space key.

```
while(true) if(Key.IsPressed(Key.Space)) Console.Write('A');
```

but when I replace `Console.Write('A');` with `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("A");` it show the message box only on the first time I press the space key (After **I close the message box** and then press space again).

Even weirder, if I change the key from space to enter it works fine.

The purpose is to create a hidden shortcut manager program so I can't use any key reader that needs focus (like `Console.ReadKey`).

Comment: "`Key.IsPressed` is using WinAPI `GetKeyState`" - So... show that code, then?

Comment: A simple `return (GetKeyState(vkCode) & 0x8000) != 0;`

Comment: This doesn't actually _wait_ for a keypress though, does it? Won't this suck up an entire CPU core by running? I can imagine that giving weird behaviour if you're lagging out your CPU. You should look into key listener methods instead...

Comment: As for the double key read, it's not surprising if this tests and outputs on every single CPU tick that the key is down. I'm surprised you're only getting two.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you use a framework method and it doesn't do what you expect, you should first [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_Windows_Forms_IWin32Window_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxButtons_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxIcon_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxDefaultButton_). There you will find information on how the `Show` method works, for example:

> A message box is a modal dialog box, which means no input (keyboard or mouse click) can occur except to objects on the modal form. The program must hide or close a modal form (typically in response to some user action) before input to another form can occur.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear. please read the edit and answer me if you can

Comment: While this doesn't explain your double key behaviour, it does show why such a thing can't happen with message boxes.